# Is it possible to use a subquery expression in a generated column?

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

I am using PostgreSQL 12, is it possible to use a query on a generated column?

I mean, using in the column creation

```
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (some query) STORED
```

Comment: **Voted to reopen.** This question is clear enough that who doesn’t find it _focused on one problem only_ really should work on their reading comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

The "some query" has to be [immutable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html), at least in version 13:

> The generation expression can refer to other columns in the table, but
> not other generated columns. Any functions and operators used must be
> immutable. References to other tables are not allowed.